# Generic types and Interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface, abstract-class, abstract

I'm trying to abstract away my simple `IRepository` entity parameter with abstract `Entity<T>` type to obey DRY principle and don't repeat `Create(this)` in child classes. But I encounter with this error:

> CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Entity' to 'T'

IRepository.cs:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Create(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> ReadAll();
}
```

Entity.cs:

```
public abstract class Entity<T>
{
    protected IRepository<T> repository;

    public void Create()
    {
        repository.Create(this);//Error occurs here on this
    }
}
```

But if make `public void Create()` abstract and implement in subclass everything went OK:

Entity.cs

```
public abstract class Entity<T>
{
    protected IRepository<T> repository;

    public abstract void Create();//Signature changed
}
```

TestEntity.cs

```
public class TestEntity:Entity<TestEntity>
{
    public override void Create()
    {
        repository.Create(this);
    }
}
```

But obviously this method will copied and paste on all subclasses of `Entity`.

> For additional help to my dear friends:

```
public abstract class Base<T>
{
    public abstract String GetName();
    public String GetMyName()
    {
        return $"My Name is :{this.GetName()} Type:{this.GetType().ToString()} Is Base<T>:{this is Base<T>}";
    }
}

public class Sample : Base<Sample>
{
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return nameof(Sample);
    }
}
```

and `MessageBox.Show(new Sample().GetMyName());` result will be:

> My Name is :Sample Type:Sample Is Base:True

without any error.

> This is another Try based one friends answer:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Create(Entity<T> entity);
    IEnumerable<T> ReadAll();
}

public abstract class Entity<T>
{
    protected IRepository<T> repository;

    public virtual void Create()
    {
        repository.Create(this);
    }
}

public class TestEntity : Entity<TestEntity>
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    public void Create(Entity<T> entity)
    {
        list.Add(this);//Error
        list.Add(entity);//Also Error
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ReadAll()
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `Entity<T>` supposed to be managing an item of type `T`? If so, where is that item defined/held?

Comment: @MatthewWatson `Entity<T>` will not manage item of type `T` but we are repeating `repository.Create(this);` on every inherited class for example in `TestEntity` and As I know one of the reasons that we use abstract class is to move repeating method/member to the abstract class.

Comment: But `this` is of type `Entity<T>`, not `T`, so there is no item of type `T` to pass to `repository.Create()`.

Comment: I've been added some additional code to answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your Entity class repository declaration, Try This:

```
public abstract class Entity<T>
    {
        protected IRepository<Entity<T>> repository;

        public void Create()
        {
            repository.Create(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `void Create(T entity);` to `void Create(Entity<T> entity);` in your `IRepository<T>` interface to make this work.

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Create(Entity<T> entity);
    IEnumerable<T> ReadAll();
}

public abstract class Entity<T>
{
    public T Value;
    protected IRepository<T> repository;

    public void Create()
    {
        repository.Create(this);
    }
}

public class TestEntity : Entity<TestEntity>
{
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    public void Create(Entity<T> entity)
    {
        list.Add(entity.Value);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> ReadAll()
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: logically same to changing `IRepository<T>` into `IRepository<Entity<T>>` and this will result in errors and unwanted complexity in the code...

Comment: @YasharAliabasi - It's not the same as `ReadAll()` still returns `IEnumerable<T>` in my answer.

Comment: Try to write a complete answer with your proposed way. You will encounter some problem(s) with `ReadAll` function(as I tested)

Comment: @YasharAliabasi - I'm not seeing the issue yet?

Comment: Because your code is incomplete...Try to implement `Repository<T>`'s `Create` function

Comment: I've been added code that I think you want to try... Take a look and get the error I'm trying to tell you.

Comment: @YasharAliabasi - You're just trying to add all sorts of things that aren't `T` to a `List<T>` so of course you're getting errors. To make this work you would need a `T Value` property on `Entity<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

Your problem comes from the fact that your `IRepository` class is expecting the type T, but your are passing it `Entity<T>` instead of T.

If you were to use this class with T being string, you would end up with this :

```
public interface IRepository<string>
{
    void Create(string entity);
    IEnumerable<string> ReadAll();
}

public abstract class Entity<string>
{
    protected IRepository<string> repository;

    public abstract void Create();//Signature changed
}

public abstract class Entity<string>
{
    protected IRepository<string> repository;

    public void Create()
    {
        //Here the compiler is expecting the parameter to be of type string, 
        //but you are passing a Entity<string> instead.
        //The compiler doesn't know how to cast it, so it throws an error.
        repository.Create(this);
    }
}
```

**Solutions**

As the other solutions say, you can make your field repository to accept `Entity<T>` instead of T, that would solve it and indeed bring more complexity.

Another solution is to modify the ´Create´ method of your interface like this :

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Create(Entity<T> entity);
    IEnumerable<T> ReadAll();
}
```

But that would force your interface to work only with Entities classes.

Comment: @YasharAliabasi My bad I didn't read correctly. but I give you the explanation on why the compiler throws an error... as there is not much other workarounds

Comment: Thank you. But I knew that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `Entity<T>` in your interface methods instead of `<T>`:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Create(Entity<T> entity);
    IEnumerable<Entity<T>> ReadAll();
}

public abstract class Entity<T>
{
    protected IRepository<T> repository;

    public void Create()
    {
        repository.Create(this);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Entity<T>> ReadAll()
    {
        return repository.ReadAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Create(this)` method sugar is possible, here is how I'm inferring on

```
    public interface IEntity
    {
    }

    public interface IEntity<T> : IEntity 
           where T : IEntity
    {
    }

    public class BaseEntity<T> : IEntity 
           where T : IEntity, IEntity<T> 
    {
    }

    public interface IRepository<T> 
           where T: IEntity
    {
        void Create(T entity);
        IEnumerable<T> ReadAll();
    }

    public class Entity<T> : BaseEntity<T> 
          where T: IEntity, 
                   IEntity<T>, 
                   IEquatable<Entity<T>>        
    {
        protected IRepository<IEntity> repository;

        public virtual void Create()
        {
            repository.Create(this);
        }

        public bool Equals(Entity<T> other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

It will defenetely adds more complexity, so better to refactor Create(this) away.